# Get GPS coordinates from an Android via a terminal?

Tags: android, gps, location, root

**How can I get GPS coordinates from an Android device via a terminal?**

I've searched *everywhere* and all I've found is Java code for apps, but not a decent method by just using a plain shell. I'm not interested in passive geo-location that uses nearby cell towers and wifi endpoints, but a method that uses the built-in GPS on a device. Is this even possible? Oh and side question:

**Is it possible to toggle GPS via a terminal when rooted without any user confirmation?**

**Edit:**

I found a way to execute what I want properly. Using `/system/bin/settings`, I can toggle GPS itself without user confirmation. After that, I can run a binary I made with Android NDK, and using JNI I can request the users current location.

Answer (score 1):

You can get latest GPS location using this adb command

```
adb shell dumpsys location
```

Comment: That requires ADB tools. I'm looking for a stock Android method.

Comment: Doesnt requires adb tools, you can use "dumpsys location" from shell